# Xvfb - Browser window does not fit display

Tags: python, xvfb, pyvirtualdisplay

I'm trying to run a web browser in a virtual display, using the Python library `pyvirtualdisplay`, which relies on `Xvfb`. The problem is that I need that browser to be maximized, something I'm not achieving. I start a display with a size of 1024x768, but the browser just takes a portion of the screen, and can't maximize it. I even tried to run the browser with flags that should open it maximized (`google-chrome -start-maximized`), with no success. As there is no button to maximize the window, I tried pressing `F11` to enter in full screen mode, but just takes the same portion of the screen.
The result can be seen in the image below:

[image]

The code I use to start the display:

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

Display(visible=1, size=(1024,768)).start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was that I was not using a window manager, so installing [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/) (a lightweight one) and running it after starting the virtual display did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

For your Chrome parameters, specify the size and position:

```
chromium browser --window-size=1280,720 --window-position=0,0
```

Comment: This really helped me in getting rid of a black border around the chromium-browser. I eventually ran "--window-position=0,0 --window-size=375,375" and that forced away the 10 pixel black border around the browser. Thanks alot, Brad!

Comment: Outstanding- works like a charm, and no additional program to run and keep track of as with fluxbox.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. If you don't want to use a full window manager, the following should work pretty well:

```
import Xlib
import Xlib.display

### Create virtual display and open the browser here ###

dpy = Xlib.display.Display()
root = dpy.screen().root
geometry = root.get_geometry()
for win in root.query_tree().children:
    win.configure(x = 0, y = 0,
        width = geometry.width, height = geometry.height)
dpy.sync()
```